# Mysql: Multiple relations between one field of a table and two fields from another table

Tags: mysql, database, join, mariadb

I try to explain it as simple as possible.
Lets say I have 2 tables in my **MySql/MariaDB** database.

```
PEOPLE (id,name)

ID  NAME
0   John
1   Jack
2   Jane
3   Lily
4   Ruth
... ...

RELATIONSHIP (id1,id2,rel)

ID1  ID2  REL
0    1    father
1    0    son
3    0    boss
2    3    daughter
3    2    mother
...  ...  ...
```

The first table contains the names of some people and the second contains the relationship between people every line tells me the relationship between two people from table `PEOPLE`).
For example the first line of table `RELATIONSHIP` tells me that `John (ID 0)` is the father of `Jack (ID 1)`.

How can I write a query that gives me the following table?

```
ID1  NAME1  ID2  NAME2  REL
0    John   1    Jack   father
1    Jack   0    John   son
3    Lily   0    John   boss
2    Jane   3    Lily   daughter
3    Lily   2    Jane   mother
...  ...    ...  ...    ...
```

Is it possible with only one query?
I can't figure out how to `join` both `ID1` and `ID2` to different lines of table `PEOPLE`.

This tables are just an example to explain what I need.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to reference and join to PEOPLE twice; each reference to the table will need a different alias, and fields referenced from them will need to be qualified by the alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply use two `join`s:

```
select r.*, p1.name as name1, p2.name as name2
from relationship r join
     people p1
     on r.id1 = p1.id join
     people p2
     on r.id2 = p2.id;
```

Comment: Man... I'm realizing how stupid my question was... Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Simply use 2 joins.

```
SELECT 
  r1.ID as ID1, 
  r1.NAME as NAME1, 
  r2.ID as ID2, 
  r2.NAME as NAME2,
  relationship.REL as REL
FROM relationship 
  JOIN PEOPLE as r1 ON relationship.ID1 = r1.ID
  JOIN PEOPLE as r2 ON relationship.ID2 = r2.ID
```

Comment: Man... I'm realizing how stupid my question was... Thank you very much! :-)